# Fractional Helly for more than one piercing

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

Fractional Helly Theorem says the following:

For every $0<\alpha\leq 1$ there exists $\beta = \beta(d, \alpha)$ with the following property. Let $C_1 , C_2 , ..., C_n$ be convex sets in $R^d$, $n \geq d + 1$, and at least $\alpha {n \choose d+1}$ of the collection 
of sets of size $d + 1$ have non-empty intersection, so there exists a point contained in at least $\beta n$ sets. Where $\beta(\alpha)=1-(1-\alpha)^\frac{1}{(d+1)}$.

Now, my question is **whether the fractional Helly is true for more that one piercing also?** More precisely, if  at least $0<\alpha'\leq 1$ fraction of ${n \choose k(d+1)}$ sets are pierced by at most $k$ points, then at least $\beta'n$ sets are pierced by at most $k$ points. Where $\beta'=\beta'(\alpha',k,d)$.